# Where do you put your app-config-files when deploying rails with capistrano and svn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, deployment, configuration-files, capistrano

I have two config-files

```
/app/config/database.yml
```

and

```
/app/config/userconfig.yml
```

i don't want to put the database credentials and userconfig in the svn-repository, so i have database.yml.dist and userconfig.yml.dist checked in.

What is the best way to get copys of the dist-files in the shared-directory when deploying the app for the first time?

For later deploys i'll link to them from /app/current/config

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should place your config files in

```
/path/to/deployed_app/shared
```

Then in a capistrano task, sym link to those files:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{release_path}/config/"
  end
end

before "deploy:restart", "deploy:symlink_shared"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Capistrano v3, you can use a task called `deploy:symlink:shared`.

Provide a list of files you placed in the shared directory, so Capistrano knows which files to symlink when the task is run. This is typically done in `deploy.rb`:

```
set :linked_files, %w{
  app/config/database.yml
  app/config/userconfig.yml
}
```

*Related: [Capistrano - How to put files in the shared folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071179/capistrano-how-to-put-files-at-the-shared-folder)*

Comment: Capistrano doesn't provide a way to upload these files from your local tree though, you'll have to do this manually (through SSH typically) or use a custom task as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23520809/814224