# Avoiding to hardcode server configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, nginx, unicorn

I'm working on a Rails application, and I'm about to open-source it.

I'm deploying it to a VPS server, configured with nginx and unicorn, following [this RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps).

In order to get Capistrano, Nginx and Unicorn working properly, I had to add some server configuration files in my `config/` folder, such as `deploy.rb`, `nginx.conf`, `unicorn.rb` and `unicorn_init.sh`.

I'm working with a git repository, and everything works under the `master` branch. In other words, Capistrano pull from it to deploy on the server, and also, that's the branch I'm about to open-source.

However I don't want that my server configuration files are public available.

What's the best solution?

Should I fork it and set one repository as the official public one, and use the other as my own version, and set the official repository as the upstream of mine?

Or it would be better to set my configuration parameters as environment variables, and left the configuration files on the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is the best one I've found for this problem (and the one I personally use).

You should place your config files in

```
/path/to/deployed_app/shared
```

Then in a capistrano task, sym link to those files:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :symlink_shared do
    run "ln -s #{shared_path}/database.yml #{release_path}/config/"
  end
end

before "deploy:restart", "deploy:symlink_shared"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done both but since it's not that sexy to look for env variables, I ended up:

- having a raw yml file to give the expected format in my repo (named like `config.yml_example`)
- having the actual `yml` files on my server in a symlinked directory

Answer (score 1):

You can still just open source the current repository if you like unless you want it to be under another name such as an organization that will host (i.e. rails/rails). Other than that you are going to want to remove those files from the git history since it sounds like you do not want them to be public see: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data for details for that.

The best way to accomplish using these configurations is to set up a shared directory on the server that is then symlinked see :[Where do you put your app-config-files when deploying rails with capistrano and svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705054/where-do-you-put-your-app-config-files-when-deploying-rails-with-capistrano-and)

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your config files under version control. Instead, create default or example versions with the `.dist` filename suffix and put the original filenames in .gitignore to prevent accidental upload. The user then has to copy `myconfig.conf.dist` to `myconfig.conf` before starting the application.

**Advantages**

- no accidental upload of configuration
- no configuration conflicts on `git pull` when the upstream configuration files are changed
- no accidental configuration change on `git pull`
- user cannot forget to adapt the configuration after `git clone`

**Disadvantages**

- adds an additional step for the user before start or deploy
- needs to be documented in the readme so that user knows about it
- users who don't read the readme may still miss it and wonder why the application does not work

P.S.: This is not Rails specific but my go to approach for all version controlled applications with configuration files.