# ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified error when trying to deploy rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, deployment

I'm getting the following error when trying to deploy my rails app with a postgresql database:

> ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: 'production' database is not
>   configured. Available: []

And this is my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host:     localhost
  pool:     20
  database: app_development

test:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host:     localhost
  pool:     20

production:
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host:     localhost
  pool:     100
  database: app_production
  username: deploy
  password:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your database.yml file making it as far as the server? I.e. it is not git ignored or somesuch?

Comment: You also are missing the `database:` key in your test: stanza

Comment: Is the database.yml configured on the server (and linked correctly if its symlinked?)

Comment: I'm pretty new to manual deployment...how do I configure it on the server?

Comment: I'm running into this issue after rebuilding the server..the same codebase was previously running successfully on the server so I don't think the database.yml file is the issue

Comment: If you deploy via capistrano, you can say that config/database.yml is a shared file (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071179/capistrano-how-to-put-files-at-the-shared-folder). On the server then you have to create a database.yml file in the deploy-folder/shared/config/database.yml...

Comment: After taking a quick look through the active record source code, it definitely seems like it's not seeing the database.yml file for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Ensure your `database.yml` and `secrets.yml` are in the right place, that is in `your_app_name/shared/config/database.yml`, same for secrets.yml.

To check, `cd` into the folders in your remote server and `ls` to list their contents.

Your database.yml should be smth like:

```
    # /home/deploy/my_app_name/shared/config/database.yml
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: my_app_name_production
  username: deploy
  password: YOUR_POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
```